# Deploying with composer on fabric

Tags: wordpress, nginx, deployment, composer-php, fabric

I am looking for the right way on doing a wordpress deployment using

- Fabric
- Composer

What I have:

- A nginx, php-fpm and mysql plataform running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- A common sudoer user, as example, I will name "**deployer**"
- A web user name **www-data** with a group named **www-data**

What I am looking for:

- Deploy a wordpress site with composer using fabric
- Deployment would be done with the sudoer user named "**deployer**" but **www-data** directory owned
- Deploy must be done on */var/www/my_wordpress_site*

Issues

- Composer couldn't write */home/deployer/.composer*, I guess composer try to use it directory since teh user used for the deploy is **deployer**
- Composer couldn't install dependences

Question:

- Could be possible to install the wordpress site on a directory like */home/deployer/my_wordpress_site* and make it nginx writable?
- What would be the right way for make deploys on web sites

**Fabric Code**

```
<pre>

STAGES = {
        'development' : {
            'hosts'       : ['deployer@deployment-server'],
            'code_dir'    : '/var/www/my_wordpress_site' ,
            'code_branch' : 'development'
            },
            ....
        }

def stage_set(stage_name='development'):
    env.stage = stage_name
    for option, value in STAGES[env.stage].items():
        setattr(env, option, value)
....

@task
def development():
    stage_set('development')

@task
def deploy():
    require('stage', provided_by=(production, staging, development))
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        if sudo("test -d %s" % env.code_dir, user='www-data', group='www-data').failed:
            sudo("git clone git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my_wordpress_site.git %s" % (env.code_dir), user='www-data', group='www-data')
            with cd(env.code_dir):
                sudo("php -r \"copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');\"", user='www-data', group='www-data')
                sudo("php -r \"if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;\"", user='www-data', group='www-data')
                sudo("php composer-setup.php", user='www-data', group='www-data')
                sudo("php -r \"unlink('composer-setup.php');\"", user='www-data', group='www-data')
                sudo("php composer.phar install --no-dev", user='www-data', group='www-data')
    with cd(env.code_dir):
        sudo("git pull", user='www-data', group='www-data')
        sudo("php composer.phar update --no-dev", user='www-data', group='www-data')
        </pre>
```